# What does this python code do?

Tags: python, exception

```
def getvalue(dictionary, name):
    try:
        return dictionary[name]
    except Exception as e:
        log = open('logfile.txt', 'w')
        log.write('%s\n' % e)
        log.close()
```

What does this code do? (I understand all of it except for the log.write part, no need to explain the rest, I just added the rest for context)

Comment: It logs the exception. `log.write('%s\n' % e)` means 'write something to the file, and use `e` as the thing to write out'. It's called string formatting.

Comment: So in other words, your question is "what does this parameter to log.write() mean?" You'd be better off asking a more specific question. "What does this code do?" is very vague and generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is roughly equivalent to `dictionary.get(name)`, except that in the case when a non-existent key is looked up, the name of the non-existent key is also written to file `logfile.txt`.  Similarly to `dict.get`, the object `None` will be returned by the function in this case, and the exception will *not* be re-raised.

You can clear things up for yourself by experimenting in the interpreter:

```
>>> d = {'some_key_which_exists': 'some_value'}
>>> d['some_key_which_exists']
'some_value'
>>> d['some_key_which_does_not_exist']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'some_key_which_does_not_exist'
>>> try:
...   d['some_key_which_does_not_exist']
... except Exception as e:
...   print '%s\n' % e
... 
'some_key_which_does_not_exist'

>>> e
KeyError('some_key_which_does_not_exist',)
```

- Note it over-writes the file, it doesn't append the file.

Answer (score 0):

It opens a file called `logfile.txt` and writes the message associated with the exception to it.

Answer (score 0):

Attempts to return the value of dictionary[name]. If it is not successful, writes an error to an external file.

Answer (score 0):

It writes the exception to logfile.txt.

%s is substituted with e (which is the Exception string representation)

\n is the new line character.

Answer (score -1):

It "tries" to return the value from the dictionary.